# Can I combine align layouts in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, layout, alignment, label, firemonkey

I want to make a label, that occupies all empty space, and at the same time has centered text.

```
// firemonkey code, 
// causes compile-time error "E2010 Incompatible types: 'TAlignLayout' and 'Set'"
GreedyLbl.Align := [TAlignLayout.alClient, TAlignLayout.alCenter];
```

I've also looked for a suitable constant on [embarcadero wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Types.TAlignLayout), but with no result. Maybe someone knows how can I make a described label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close. Try setting the `Align` to just `TAlignLayout.alClient`. Then set the `TextAlign` to `TTextAlign.taCenter`.

The `Align` property is part of `TControl` and comes into play anytime there is a control with a visual aspect to it.

The `TextAlign` property only involves controls descended from `TTextControl`, like a `TLabel`. (Also: `TTextControl` descends from `TControl`).